# Failed to retrieve street address from cordinates

Tags: android

I am trying to get the full address by providing longitude and latitude coordinates. for now i succedd to get the coordinates correctly
this is what i get:

```
my coordinates﹕ 32.6653854,35.1051237
```

now when i use getCompleteAddressString()
i get all the time exception:

```
Current location address﹕ Can not get Address!
```

this is my getCompleteAddressString function:

```
 public String getCompleteAddressString(double LATITUDE, double LONGITUDE, Context ctx) {
    String strAdd = "";
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(ctx, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(LATITUDE, LONGITUDE, 1);
        if (addresses != null) {
            Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder strReturnedAddress = new StringBuilder("");

            for (int i = 0; i < returnedAddress.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                strReturnedAddress.append(returnedAddress.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
            }
            strAdd = strReturnedAddress.toString();
            Log.w("My Current location address", "" + strReturnedAddress.toString());
        } else {
            Log.w("My Current location address", "No Address returned!");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.w("My Current location address", "Can not get Address!");
    }
    return strAdd;
}
```

and this is the class where i try to run it:

```
@Override
public void updateUI() {
    Log.d("my location","updateUI");
    Log.d("get coordinates","my location");
    String realAddress = myLocManager.getCompleteAddressString(myLocManager.getmLastLocation().getLatitude(),myLocManager.getmLastLocation().getLatitude(),this.getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    Log.d("my coordinates", String.valueOf(myLocManager.getmLastLocation().getLatitude()+","+myLocManager.getmLastLocation().getLongitude()));
    Log.d("my real address",realAddress);
    if(realAddress != null)
        streetAddress.setText(realAddress);
}
```

i try to run updateUI also with getActivity() method but still i got the same error.
when i used LocationManager in other app it was work good.

Comment: What's the exception you get?

Comment: i found that in this lins is failed Address returnedAddress = addresses.get(0); its mean that he didnt found any address but it not make sense

Comment: failed with which exception?

Comment: Did you add permission in AndroidManifest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was my mistake i call the method with the wrond parameters:

```
getmLastLocation().getLatitude(),myLocManager.getmLastLocation().getLatitude()
```

i pass the Latitude param twice